# JAXBException occurred : class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb, annotations, bind

The client code looks like:

```
String urlGetRequestsByCustomer = baseUrl + "getRequestsByCustomer?customerID=";

byte[] getRequestsByCustomerResponse = customerAgent
.sendGetMethod(urlGetRequestsByCustomer + custNo);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = customerAgent
.getUnmarshaller(ServiceRequests.class);
 StringReader reader = new StringReader(new String(
getRequestsByCustomerResponse));
```

ServiceRequests.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class ServiceRequests {


@XmlElement(name = "serviceRequest", type = ServiceRequest.class)
private List<ServiceRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ServiceRequest>();

/**
 * 
 */
public ServiceRequests() {
}

public ServiceRequests(List<ServiceRequest> requests) {
    this.requests = requests;
}

/**
 * @return the requests
 */
public List<ServiceRequest> getRequests() {
    return requests;
}

/**
 * @param requests
 *            the requests to set
 */
public void setRequests(List<ServiceRequest> requests) {
    this.requests = requests;
}
```

}

ServiceRequest.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SERVICE_REQUEST", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames=
{"SRNO"})})
@SequenceGenerator(name="SERVICE_REQUEST_SEQUENCE",     
sequenceName="SERVICE_REQUEST_SEQUENCE", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="serviceRequest.getBySrNo",query="SELECT request from ServiceRequest 
request WHERE request.srNo = :srNo")
})

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class ServiceRequest implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5047875961706019225L;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
generator="SERVICE_REQUEST_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name="SRNO",  nullable=false)
private Long srNo;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@Column(name="STATUS") 
private int status;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name="CUSTNO", referencedColumnName="CustNO")
private Customer customer;

@Column(name="DATECREATED")
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name="DATEUPDATED")
private Date dateUpdated;

@Column(name="UPDATEDBY")
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name="updatedBy")
private Employee updatedBy;

public Employee getUpdatedBy() {
    return updatedBy;
}


public void setUpdatedBy(Employee updatedBy) {
    this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
}


@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="serviceRequest", 
cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
private CustomerSurvey survey;


/**
 * @return the dateUpdated
 */
public Date getDateUpdated() {
    return dateUpdated;
}


/**
 * @param dateUpdated the dateUpdated to set
 */
public void setDateUpdated(Date dateUpdated) {
    this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
}


/**
 * @return the survey
 */
public CustomerSurvey getSurvey() {
    return survey;
}


/**
 * @param survey the survey to set
 */
public void setSurvey(CustomerSurvey survey) {
    this.survey = survey;
}

public ServiceRequest() {
}


/**
 * @return the srNo
 */
public Long getSrNo() {
    return srNo;
}

/**
 * @param srNo the srNo to set
 */
public void setSrNo(Long srNo) {
    this.srNo = srNo;
}

/**
 * @return the description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/**
 * @param description the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

/**
 * @return the status
 */
public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

/**
 * @param status the status to set
 */
public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

/**
 * @return the customer
 */
public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

/**
 * @param customer the customer to set
 */
public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

/**
 * @return the dateCreated
 */
public Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

/**
 * @param dateCreated the dateCreated to set
 */
public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((dateCreated == null) ? 0 : dateCreated.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((dateUpdated == null) ? 0 : dateUpdated.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + (int) (srNo ^ (srNo >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + status;
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof ServiceRequest)) {
        return false;
    }
    ServiceRequest other = (ServiceRequest) obj;
    if (dateCreated == null) {
        if (other.dateCreated != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!dateCreated.equals(other.dateCreated)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (dateUpdated == null) {
        if (other.dateUpdated != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!dateUpdated.equals(other.dateUpdated)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (description == null) {
        if (other.description != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!description.equals(other.description)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (srNo != other.srNo) {
        return false;
    }
    if (status != other.status) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ServiceRequest [srNo=" + srNo + ", description=" + description
            + ", status=" + status + ", dateCreated=" + dateCreated
            + ", dateUpdated=" + dateUpdated + "]";
}
}
```

I m getting the message as: 
    Method failed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    JAXBException occurred : class
    javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity nor any of its super class is known to this context.. 
    class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity nor any of its super class is known to this 
    context..

I m new to xml annotations.
Please advice .....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some JPA implementations manipulate the byte codes of the entity classes.  This can involve adding fields.  Since you are using field access with your JAXB mappings you may have been affected by this.  I would recommend using `PROPERTY` access instead and moving your annotations to the `get` methods.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html